# Laravel ambiguous string search

Tags: laravel-5

I have a problem about search. 
I can make basic search. I would like to make more advanced search 
Like search.

For example. database's table has "AAA" string at 'pn' colum.
I would like to show the record when I type "aaa" search text area.

I made this below but it didn't work. 
Could somebody tell me what is the problem please?

```php
public function show(Request $request)
{
    if (isset($request->pn)) {
        $param = ['pn' => $request->pn];
        $item = DB::select('select * from sts where pn collate utf8_unicode_ci like '%'.$pn.'%'', $param);      
    } else {
        $items = DB::select('select * from sts');
    }
    return view('pn.searchshow', ['items' => $items]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binding has to include the `%` wildcards:

```php
$param = ['pn' => '%'.$request->pn.'%'];
$item = DB::select('select * from sts where pn collate utf8_unicode_ci like :pn', $param);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! it workded very well! You made my day!

Answer (score 0):

```
public function show(Request $request)
{
    $query = \DB::table('sts');
    if (isset($request->pn)) {
        $query->where(DB::raw('`pn` callate utf8_unicode_ci'), 'like', '"%' . $request->pn . '%"');
    }

    $items = $query->get();
    return view('pn.searchshow', ['items' => $items]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I just soloved this problem by.Mr Jonas anser. but Thank you so much. I will try out your way.

Comment: I downvoted your answer. Using unfiltered user input like this is extremely dangerous ([SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)). NEVER do that!

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir i know [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) but your code also has sql injection

Comment: @blueink for prevent sql injection i will update my answer

Comment: @Davit Sorry for late reply. Thank you so much!